# Filter records based on Date Range + ASP.NET + Regex + Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, filter

I need to filter data based on a date range.

My table has a field Process date. I need to filter the records and display those in the range FromDate to ToDate.

How do I write a function in VB.NET which can help me filter the data.

Am I on the right track??

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you do yourself a favor and DateTime.Parse your strings and use Date comparison operators

Something like

```
 Function ObjectInRange(ByRef obj As Object, ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String) As Boolean
        Dim date1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(str1)
        Dim date2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(str2)

        Dim inRange = False

        For Each prop As PropertyInfo In obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            Dim propVal = prop.GetValue(obj, Nothing)
            If propVal Is Nothing Then
                Continue For
            End If
            Dim propValString = Convert.ToString(propVal)
            Dim propValDate = DateTime.Parse(propValString)
            If propValDate.CompareTo(date1) > 0 And propValDate.CompareTo(date2) < 0 Then
                inRange = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Return inRange

    End Function
```

Comment: Yeah I did something like that... I was just thinking too much.. thanks anyway!